# What does the '@' mean before a bash variable with the date command?

Tags: bash, date, unix

I'm working on a bash script that checks if a backup has been made in the last X days. The script must be run on linux and macos. My problem is, that when it checks if it's running on a linux or macos system, I don't understand what the **'@'** means before the 'bckpT' variable on linux part.

```
case "$OS" in
   DARWIN)
       lastBackup=$($DATE -u -r $bckpT +%F)
       ;;

   LINUX)
       lastBackup=$($DATE -d @$bckpT +%F)
       ;;

   WIN)
       $ECHO "No script for WIN"
       ;;

   *)
       help
       ;;
esac
```

When there isn't the '@', the output is:

> /usr/bin/date: invalid date '1647907200'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `date` command the `@` sign tells the command to treat the following as `seconds since epoch`

In your case, it consider the param `$bckpT` value as seconds since epoch